# Is there a more efficient way to check characters in a string?

Tags: java

For this assignment, I need to accept a lock combination and check if:

- It is 9 chars long
- At position 2,8 the char is R or r
- At position 5 the char is l or L
- All of the other positions are integers 0-9

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this than checking each position for a digit?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String lockComb;
System.out.print("Please enter a lock combination ( ddRddLddR ): ");
lockComb = input.nextLine();

if((lockComb.length() == 9) && ((lockComb.charAt(2) == 'r') || (lockComb.charAt(2) == 'R')) && 
    ((lockComb.charAt(5) == 'l') || (lockComb.charAt(5) == 'L')) && ((lockComb.charAt(8) == 'r') 
        || (lockComb.charAt(8) == 'R')))
{
    if((Character.isDigit(lockComb.charAt(0))) && (Character.isDigit(lockComb.charAt(1))) && 
        (Character.isDigit(lockComb.charAt(3)) && (Character.isDigit(lockComb.charAt(4))) && 
            (Character.isDigit(lockComb.charAt(6))) && (Character.isDigit(lockComb.charAt(7)))))
    {
        System.out.println(lockComb + " is a valid lock combination!"); 
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println(lockComb + " is not a valid lock combination!");
    }
}

else
{
    System.out.println(lockComb + " is not a valid lock combination!");
}
```

Comment: For a problem this simple, don't worry about performance unless you can actually measure the performance as being bad (i.e. don't do premature optimization!).  Just try to make the code look clean so that anyone who comes after you can understand it quickly.  (I only say this because of the word "efficient" in your post.)

Comment: You can use regular expressions, but I'm not sure if that is allowed for you in your assignment. Using regular expressions, you can simply check to see if the string matches the pattern `/^\d{2}[rR]\d{2}[lL]\d{2}[rR]$/` For an introductory assignment like this, I would be surprised if you were tasked with using a regex.

Comment: Without studying it in detail, that's not an unreasonable way to approach it.  Folks that are into it would come up with an unintelligible solution using "regular expressions", and others might use some sort of table-driven approach.  (Do note that you may save a bit by doing a toUpperCase or toLowerCase on the incoming string, to avoid having to do double compares.)

Comment: That depends on what you define as "better". Performance-wise, that will be quite efficient already. If you want to have smaller/cleaner code, consider concatenating the remaining characters and test if the result is a number. Or go for a Regex solution, although that does add some perfomance overhead (if that's relevant).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To simplify things, you can use a regular expression:

```
if (lockComb.matches("[0-9][0-9][rR][0-9][0-9][lL][0-9][0-9][rR]")
```

(That's lowercase-l and uppercase-L in the middle.)

(No need to check the length, which is implicitly defined by the regular expression.)

Comment: Why do you need the length check? Also, if efficiency is a concern, then the regex should be pre-compiled via `Pattern` and used with `Matcher`.

Comment: Because the regex, as is, will match strings longer than 9.  (Alternately, he could surround the regex with "^" and "$" and get rid of the length check.)

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier No; `matches()` matches against the entire string already.

Comment: @arshajii You are right; the length check can be removed.

Comment: @arshajii - No, that's not right.  It checks if the string contains the regex.  It will match this: "xxx01r23l45rxxx" because the middle section matches the regex.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier My regular expression correctly fails to match `"xxx01r23l45rxxx"`.

Comment: While the length check is obviously not necessary, I would still leave it in. If the code is often called with strings of a different length than 9 characters this does improve the performance, as the regex matcher won't be called.

Comment: @arshajii, You guys are right and I am wrong.  I guess I'm confusing this with Ruby.

Comment: You could shorten your regex using `\d{2}` etc

Comment: @samiam0295 -- Remember, if you use a regex solution you'll need to be able to explain what you're doing to your instructor.

Answer (score 2):

How about just for fun a solution that doesn't involve regular expressions.  I'm not arguing at all for or against just merely a different solution.  One thing you do lose if using a regular expression is the ability to tell exactly why this is not a valid lock combination.  It's up to you to figure out what the best solution is given the scenario you are coding for.

```
public static boolean matcher (String lockComb) {
    if(lockComb.length() != 9) {
        System.out.println(lockComb + " is not a valid lock combination!");
        return false;
    }
    boolean isValid = true;

    char[] comb = lockComb.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < comb.length; i++) {
        switch (i) {
        case 2:
        case 8:
            isValid = (comb[i] == 'R');
            break;
        case 5:
            isValid = (comb[i] == 'L');
            break;
        default:
            isValid = Character.isDigit(comb[i]);
            break;
        }
        if(isValid == false) break;
    }
    if(isValid) {
        System.out.println(lockComb + " is a valid lock combination!");
    } else {
        System.out.println(lockComb + " is not a valid lock combination!");
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Don't `break` from the loop - use `isValid` as a second loop condition instead, as that improves the readability of your code.